# Problem with lost file by deleting (CTRL Z NOT WORKING)

Tags: modeling, mesh

today happended most unfortunate situation for me, i was working on model for 4-5 hours and i was tired, so instead of hiding objects i started to delete objects and now i cant recover them back by ctrl + z. I was terribly tired and didn't know what i was doing is there any way to get it back please!

Comment: Hi :). *File > Recover > Autosave* could help :))

Comment: Hey! it wont work cause blender dont saves blend files itself, it only saves when i quit blender or it crashes itself.

Comment: It should do if you have Autosave turned on in Preferences > Save & Load!

Comment: Oh... I have it off thats why! Alright i cant get back model so i will try to do it again thank you def will help for future! :D

Comment: If you haven't turned it off, Blender creates a backup file of the last version as *\*.blend1* in the same directory when you save the blend. Maybe you can recover your models from the old save?